# Creating Link For User To Delete Row

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I'd like to ask two things for this particular user ability. The first is how to delete a row upon user clicking a button. The second is....would this be a good idea? How can I create a safe environment for someone to do this. This is what I've got so far :

```
<?php

include_once "db_conx.php";

    if($_POST['wall'] == "post") {
    //open if($_POST['wall'] == "post")
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, trim($_POST['id1']));
            if($id == " ")
                {
                    exit();
                }
                else
            $sql = "SELECT FROM courseprogress WHERE userid='$id' LIMIT 1";
            $results = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $sidebar = mysqli_num_rows($results);
                if($sidebar > 0) {
                //close if($sidebar > 0)
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
                    {
                        $sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM courseprogress WHERE userid='$id'");
                        $results = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

                    }
                //close if($sidebar > 0)

                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Already Complete!';
                    echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump($sql);
                        echo "</pre><br>";
                }



    //close if($_POST['wall'] == "post")
    }



?>
```

Right now I'm in the process of dumping out variables, but can't seem to get my id variable right.

The idea is to "start over" in a sense. The table holds the user progression and settings. Once they've decided they need to start over they will be allowed to do so by simply deleting the row. When the begin again the row will be created again.

**A little more information:**

The small form script I was trying to use is:

```
<div class="userInfoContain"><div class="positionRight"><div id="form"> <form><div class="submit"><input type="hidden" id="id" value="'.$id.'" /><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Start Over" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:wall();"/><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" width="15" height="15" id="loadingstart" /></div></form></div></div></div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                         $('#loadingstart').hide();
                                        });

                                        function wall(){
                                        $('#loadingstart').show();
                                          var id = $('#id').val();  
                                          var URL = "./includes/start-over-user.php"; /////post.php will be equal the variable "comment"

                                          $.post(URL,{wall:"post",id1:id},function(data){//parameter wall will be equal "post", name1 will be equal to the var "name" and comment1 will be equal to the var "comment"
                                          $("#result").prepend(data).show();// the result will be placed above the the #result div
                                          $('#loadingstart').hide();
                                          });
                                         }
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) **Safely allow user to delete:** The safest way is to not allow delete permissions on the MySQL user that is being used by the website. A method called soft delete is much safer for deleting rows in MySQL tables. This involves adding a column named "is_deleted" to the table where you are making this update. When is_deleted is set to 0, allow the row to act normally. When a user sets is_deleted to 1, it should act as if it doesn't exist. In this example, I am assuming you have set $is_deleted to the column is_deleted in your table:

```
if($is_deleted == '1')
{
    // Don't display
}
else
{
    // Display
}
```

2) **How to implement:** The best way to do this is with:

```
UPDATE tablename SET is_deleted = '1' WHERE id = '".$id."'
```

which should be executed through AJAX command or a link that will execute the MySQL query.

Comment: Would you go enum on is_delete?

Comment: @Chris I would use bit or tinyint if you want to have different levels of is_deleted.

Answer (score 0):

to delete I advice you to use ajax , it's perfect and you can have more control on this action
the other Problem i need more explanation i didn't understand you good